# xpath to get URLs in Google sheet from XML

Tags: xml, wordpress, xpath, google-sheets

I am trying to import all the URLs from this [page](https://www.mangoblogger.com/wp-sitemap-posts-post-1.xml) in a Google Sheet.

The formula I am using is

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.mangoblogger.com/wp-sitemap-posts-page- 1.xml","//*[@id=""sitemap__table""]/tbody/tr/td/a")
```

But I am getting an error. I tried multiple variations of xpath (/a,tbody/tr etc), but no luck.

What would be the xpath to use in the formula to bring in all the URLs from given URL?

P:S - This XML URL is auto-generated by Wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that when I saw the data from the URL of `https://www.mangoblogger.com/wp-sitemap-posts-post-1.xml`, I confirmed that the data is the XML data. So, how about the following xpath?

#### Sample xpath:

```
//*[local-name()='loc']
```

#### Sample formula:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.mangoblogger.com/wp-sitemap-posts-post-1.xml","//*[local-name()='loc']")
```

#### Result:

[image]

#### Reference:

- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: @mango Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.